# Changing shape of div element

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have a div element with some text in it and i want to shape my div element like a polygon or hexagon and i want the text to be in it the same way. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sort of. Look into CSS clip paths: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: thanks this is the easiest and best method i got till now.

Comment: Maybe a good case to use an SVG?

Comment: creating and then animating using svg is little tough job for me. so i was searching for an easy way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everybody (including the OP for whatever reason) are missing the part of **"i want the text to be in it the same way"**

That's the tricky part here. If you make the shape with clip-path, the text will still be boxy, and will be butchered out.

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

p{color:white; background:steelblue}
```

```html
<div> 
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
</div>
```

While any other regular way of drawing the polygon will have the text behaving as a square, not interacting with the shape at all.

The only way I can think of is using shape-outside, and drawing the shape by negatives. Something like:

```css
.polygon{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:steelblue;
}

.top-left, .top-right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:white;
}

.top-left {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 50%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 50%, 100% 0);
  float: left;
}

.top-right {
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 0);
  float: right;
}

p{
  color:white;
  padding:1em;
  word-break:break-all
}
```

```html
<div class="polygon">
  <div class="top-left"> </div>
  <div class="top-right"> </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipi sicing elit. Enim eos magnam similique id expedita quibusdam, fuga, corporis doloremque sit dicta sint atque laboriosam repellat, exercitationem hic! Saepe necessitatibus tempora rerum</p>
</div>
```

This is, of course, ridiculously complex, fragile and [incompatible with IE, Edge, and Firefox.](https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside) There is [a polyfill available though](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, changing the shape of a single div into a hexagon or other polygon can not be done. But there is way of doing triangles, hexagons and other using css:

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 173.21px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 86.60px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 86.60px solid #64C7CC;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"> <div class="content"> asdf </div> </div>
```

That was from http://csshexagon.com
You can also look in here to see more examples of other shapes: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

As I said, this is as far as I know, maybe there is a way of doing so, but I think this is easier

I edited the answer and added the content for it to be centered in the hexagon.

Comment: i kinda did almost the same bt when i used animation on it everything fell apart but thanks for the code.

Comment: yw, I didn't know there was a way neither. Hope it helps anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [How to recreate 6 hexagon shape background in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999780/how-to-recreate-6-hexagon-shape-background-in-css) ?  This seems to be a very similar scenario, with some interesting additions to also chain hexagons together.